# Where can I buy a good, but cheap D&D board?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I'm looking to buy a real D&D game board, with all the pieces and brand new, but all i can find are extremely expensive sets. I am based in the UK and am looking to spend up to a max of £50, preferably less. Also, is there a certain board that i should buy? I know there are certain ones that you can build and others that are pre built, which one is better?

Comment: Note that D&D isn't a board game; the only kinds of boards that could be sold are either highly generic, to allow you to build your own, or extremely specific, only serving as a board for a particular location (as a part of a particular published adventure, perhaps). Most games of D&D don't really use anything like this, though I gather they can be nice. Just in case you're new to the hobby and think you *need* to buy one.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [I'm at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/4563) for a pretty good introduction to how it works.

Comment: There are also boardgames under the D&D brand, but they aren't typically what we're talking about when we speak of D&D

Comment: Helpful links: [what are roleplaying games](http://learntabletoprpgs.com/index.html) (if you're curious), and [the Stack Exchange for boardgames](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) (where you'll find help with the D&D boardgames).

Answer (score 4):

**D&D isn't really a board game, *per se*.** You can make a map, spread it out on a table, and put pieces on it to keep track of what's going on, and many people do this. But D&D doesn't come with one, and you don't really *need* one to play.

**This said, the folks behind D&D *have* made some board games based on specific adventures**. *Castle Ravenloft* is based on an old classic, for example, while *The Legend of Drizzt* is based on a series of novels that was itself spawned from a popular setting. I haven't actually played these, but I hear good things about them. The board games aren't really D&D, despite the branding, but they might make a decent introduction to some of the concepts behind it.