# I want to take part!

Tags: new-players

I've been perusing the questions on this forum for sometime now and I think I'm developing an interest in taking part in an adventure.

I see a lot of people take part online or over Skype.

Would anyone have any suggestions on the best way to get started?

I'm a 100% novice, other than playing Baldur's Gate and similar games.
Are there any websites / forums that could help me out?

I'd like to meet some people, develop a character and take part in an adventure.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, unfortunately your question doesn't really fit our format (I voted to close). Its too broad and doesn't have any specifications for what would be a good answer to it. Its probably better suited to a forum or in our chatroom http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith I think this site, as a knowledge base, needs questions and answer about how to get started, this way all newbies can be redirected to it. Like this http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/im-at-a-loss-with-dungeons-and-dragons-how-does-one-play-it-anyway , but system-agnostic. Doesn't this question exist? Answers could provide a small introduction to the hobby, a handful of novice advices, and links to interesting stuff.

Comment: @Flamma I think I agree with your sentiments or at least your desire but I can't think of a way such a question could be framed appropriately. The very lack of knowledge that leads someone to ask how to get into the hobby is the same lack of knowledge that would prevent them from writing a question with meaningful requirements and goals. I could suggest any of the various RPGs I've ever played and they'd all be "right" because there was nothing defining what was in scope or out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet is full of information about roleplaying games. RPG community is anxious to show other people how to play and would love them to join or at least understand our hobby.

You can try a simple search as "how to play rpg". This is the first result for me:

http://learntabletoprpgs.com/index.html

Which seems to have information to start. There are even links to quickstart version of the games. I would recommend to start with a very simple system, so I don't think D&D or Pathfinder are good novice choices. But that's only my opinion.

Of course, possibly the best way to learn would be to join a group of people that are already playing. I have always played with friends, but I know there are groups that take players that don't previously know. There are many online sites to create/join these groups.

Comment: Cheers Flamma, appreciate the informative response man!

Comment: @Daft No problem. Welcome to the site. Don't take personally criticism of the question above. The site tries to be quite rigorous in order to generate utile Q&A, and it can be quite tricky for beginners to ask a question according to this format. Stay on the site for a while and you will learn the style.

Comment: oh yeah I knew I was gonna get a few close votes for that question, I use a bunch of the other stack overflow sites. But I was hoping someone would help me out all the same, 

Answer (score 2):

This is not really in the best format for this site. However, I would suggest checking out reddit.com/r/lfg or roll20.net for groups that are looking and accepting of new players. Pathfinder is a system that is open source so you can get access to the rules for free and can help you get into the game. Those are available at paizo.com/prd

I wish you luck in your adventures :D

Comment: That is true, I don't feel like the reference site is missing much from the book though other than fluff and pre-gen characters which are easily made in any generator. I will edit it to reflect that though.