# Need Help Explaining DnD

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I am going to be starting a D&D club at my school but need help explaining what D&D is to the principal to get the idea accepted. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you think the principal knows what a Role Playing Game is at all, or does your explanation need to cover that as well?

Comment: No I do not believe he does so just in case I think it should.

Comment: I think we need more details, especially: are there any formal guidelines or requirements for student clubs? A copy of those would allow us to answer them directly. As is, this is kind of a problematic question, there’s not enough information about what it is you need to know.

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer the question as posed, but you may want to look at the answers to [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/15469) question for some ideas.

Comment: No problem! You've got enough rep to [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) if you want to talk about this with site users.