# I'm pretty new to d&d

Tags: new-players

I always wanted to play D&D but i was always "friendless" amd live in a very urban area where no one plays i learn better if others teach me are there any videos that anyone could suggest that is helpful or any groups that are willing to take beginners?

Comment: Hi Potate, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. There's some questions on this topic already, and this question has been closed as a duplicate of some of them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! This is a pretty basic question—probably the first question *anyone* has about D&D—so we already have some pretty good answers to it. In addition to that one, there’s some related stuff like [I’m at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/4563) and [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232/4563)

Comment: The answers to the other questions lack detailled information about online gaming, is there a way to make it appear somewhere ?

Comment: @Boulash Which “it” are you referring to? One of the questions linked here is specifically all about online play.

Comment: It refers to comprehensive info about online gaming. The answer I could find only mentions Roll20 (but I might have missed something)