# Can you recommend some good blogs or video tutorials on Dungeons & Dragons 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, online-resources

advise good blogs or video tutorials on D&D, I have already studied [the manual](https://5thsrd.com/), but rn there is a mess in my head, I want to somehow sort it all out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Totally fair question, but unfortunately not one we can help with: our format just doesn’t work well for this sort of thing. Check out the [Tour] for more info, if you like. If you spend some time here, you could try our [Chat], where I suspect plenty of people have suggestions, but unfortunately you need a little bit of reputation here (just two upvotes, just to keep out spam). Otherwise, we do have some [discussion forums we recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563), which may be better suited to your question.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [I'm at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/im-at-a-loss-with-dungeons-and-dragons-how-does-one-play-it-anyway)

Comment: Do you have a specific question about some rule or game element?

Comment: Since your name implies Star Wars, you might be interested to know we [have a site about that stuff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)