# How can i play D&D and enjoy it with my dad?

Tags: new-players, system-introduction

Good afternoon, i apologize if the question has already been asked or is not a valid question, but i would like to ask for tips and maybe if it's possible to know like servers/chats or places where people play and maybe help people like me to know how to play with other people. I know that may sound dumb, and i apologize if it's bothersome for someone, i bought a D&D game(it's the first one i see in my country so i didn't want to miss the chance to buy it), i read the rules(it's a lil tricky, but compared to every official rule book i've seen, this one is for dummies like me hehe), as i don't have anyone to play with, i wanted maybe to play with my dad(he's 50 years old), but i don't know what would be a good approach for someone who's not used to play this kind of games(he has played things like monopoly sure), so may i ask for advice if possible?

I saw there was a chat here, but i couldn't ask there because of reputation thingie, i apologize if this is something like spam or my english was bad.

Comment: Welcome to the site Nero. The question as written is a bit broad for our Q&A format, so I’ve voted to close for “needs focus”. However, you only need 20 rep to [chat], and I’ve contributed 10 of that with an upvote.

Comment: This looks like it may be answered already by [I'm new to D&D: where to begin?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204623/42375), though you're way ahead since you already have (and even read!) the book

Comment: Oh i understand, my bad i apologize for the trouble and will ask there, thank you for your help c:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm new to D&D: where to begin?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204623/im-new-to-dd-where-to-begin)