# Just started D&D, what does it mean for me to be proficient in a skill and other problems - please help!

Tags: dnd-5e

I just started learning about Dungeons and Dragons. I am currently trying to fill out the form on https://levi-blodgett.github.io/dnd-char-generator/, but I'm having trouble filling things in. (The one you will see isn't mine, just a computer generated one.)

For instance:  what does it mean for me to be proficient in a skill?
Does it make my other skills not work?
How many do I get (skills)
What does a skills type (ex: wisdom) do to a skill?
And what are hit points, temporary hit points, and what does it mean to have an advantage on saving throws against being charmed?
I don't mean to sound like a dummy, but I've just started and don't understand how I should choose all the numbers that need to be chosen and what to add to them based on my class, race, and XP.
Plus, what do I put in the tiny 'inspiration' box? What do the letters next to the boxes mean, like cp, sp, ep, pp, and what number do I put next to them, in the box? What am I even doing on the third page?

As you can see, these are big problems I don't know the answers to, and their answers are necessary to play the game. I hope someone can answer, because DnD sounds fun, and I'm pretty lost. None of my friends play this game (that I know.) So please help! pretty much I need a little write about... most of the squares. Or all. Yeah, I'm *really* lost. But I really need the help!

Comment: Hi, Elodie, welcome to the RPG Stack exchange-- take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already.  Two very strong suggestions, to get good answers:  First, this site works best with one question (or a very few closely related questions) per post.  Second, we're going to need to know which version of the game you need help with.  It's probably not both 5e (the current version) and 2e (which hasn't been published for a very long time.)

Comment: Hi Elodie, and welcome to the hobby. You've got lots of questions, and reasonable ones. I'm not sure Q&A format's actually going to be the best for this, but I'm going to throw an upvote your way and invite you to join us in [chat]--I suspect a few minutes' back-and-forth there may be a preferable path forward. Also, I'm going to link some related questions momentarily....

Comment: Welcome to the stack Elodie, take the [tour] when you have a moment. This isn’t really the site to look to for being taught the basics of the game. We deal with more focused questions, and we don’t really do broad tutorial like questions. If you haven’t already, the first seven chapters or so of [the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) address all of your questions here. Read through those first, then if something specific from those rules is confusing, we may be able to help.

Comment: @Elvina It looks like you need the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules), to start getting a grasp on the game. See also the answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/15991) on how the game is played. From there you will be able to ask more specific questions about things you still don't understand.

Answer (score 9):

### These questions and more can be answered by reading the freely-available [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules).

However, here are specific answers to your specific questions:

#### What does it mean for me to be proficient in a skill?

> A skill represents a specific aspect of an ability score, and an individual's proficiency in a skill demonstrates a focus on that aspect.

[Basic rules, chapter 7](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Skills).

#### Does proficiency make my other skills not work?

No, other skills still work just fine.

#### How many skill proficiencies do I get?

By and large, skill proficiencies are granted by your [class](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes), your [background](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Backgrounds), and sometimes your [race](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/races). Other sources (such as feats and downtime) are also available, but talk to your DM about those.

#### What does a skill's type (e.g. Wisdom) do to a skill?

> Each ability covers a broad range of capabilities, including skills that a character or a monster can be proficient in.

[Basic rules, chapter 7](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Skills).

The ability and possibly your proficiency bonus are used to figure out what you add to a d20 roll when it is called for by your DM.

#### What are hit points?

> Hit points represent a combination of physical and mental durability, the will to live, and luck. Creatures with more hit points are more difficult to kill. Those with fewer hit points are more fragile.

[Basic rules, chapter 9](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#HitPoints).

#### What are temporary hit points?

> Temporary hit points aren't actual hit points; they are a buffer against damage, a pool of hit points that protect you from injury.

[Basic rules, chapter 9](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints).

#### What does it mean to have an advantage on saving throws against being charmed?

For this, read about [advantage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AdvantageandDisadvantage), read about [saving throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#SavingThrows), and read about [the charmed condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed).

#### I've just started and don't understand how I should choose all the numbers that need to be chosen.

Follow the steps in the [basic rules, chapter 1: Step-By-Step Characters](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters).

#### What do I put in the tiny 'inspiration' box?

When you have [inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Inspiration), you can put a one, a checkmark, a heart, a dot, or any other marker to represent *having it* in that box.

#### What do the letters next to the boxes mean, like cp, sp, ep, pp?

They mean Copper Piece, Silver Piece, Electrum Piece, and Platinum Piece. Also, gp means Gold Piece. See the [basic rules, chapter 5](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#Wealth).

#### What number do I put next to cp, sp, ep, and pp?

See the "Choose Equipment" step in the [basic rules, chapter 1: Step-By-Step Characters](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters#5ChooseEquipment).

#### What am I even doing on the third page?

This is for tracking things related to spellcasting, which you may have depending on your choice of class. Read the rules for your class, and the [basic rules, chapter 10: Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting) to understand more.

### "None of my friends play this game (that I know.)"

I would highly recommend that if you can fit it in your budget, you pick up a physical box set called the [Starter Set](https://dndstore.wizards.com/us/product/811467/dd-starter-set-digital-plus-physical-bundle) (the one with a blue dragon on the front). Schedule a session to play with three to five friends, choose one player to be the Dungeon Master ahead of time and have them read both booklets before the scheduled session, and then start the session by having the Dungeon Master read the rules booklet to the group; this will take 60–90 minutes, but it's well worth it. This will give the group everything they need to start playing, which will take up the remaining 2½–3 hours of the session. If you all enjoyed it, there's enough content in that box to continue for about three more 4-hour sessions!