# Anyone have some links to "easy to read" resources for a DND newbie?

Tags: new-players, dnd-4e

Howdy! I am about to start a campaign with some friends in a month or so when they finish their current game. We will be using the 4e rules and characters. My wife has expressed interest in playing with us. While I am excited, I am also mortified.

I need some links to very easy to read / follow resources that explain the classes and combat system. When I start talking to her about the mechanics, her eyes glaze over and she just tunes out. Lucky for me most of the folks we play with are more story driven and willing to help out, but I'd like to find some resources that will give her a good intro.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Chris! Welcome! Check out [Playing 4th Ed D&D for the first time...](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/419) for some ideas.

Comment: Also: [What is role-playing, and where do I start?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4457) `:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a technical point of view, the RedBox set is a great self-paced introduction to the mechanics of D&D.

Answer (score 1):

Search Amazon for "Dungeon and Dragons for Dummies"  You'll find dozens of books and authors that might help.  There's more than one person who makes a living from writing that kind of guide.