# How to read creature attack stats and defense stats

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage

I am trying to setup a game for my players (GM). I am new to this and I am trying to figure out what some of these creature stats mean.

> Melee short sword +3 (1d6+1/19-20)

Do I divide by 19-20, or do I need to roll between a 19-20 for this to succeed?

Also ran across an Artic Tatzlwyrm and it states the below.

> **Tatzlwyrm poison:** Breath—inhaled; save Fort DC 12; frequency 1/round for 2 rounds; effect 1d2 Str damage; cure 1 save. The save DC is Constitution-based.

Have no Idea about the above.

> Melee bite +5 (1d8+3 plus grab)
>   Special Attacks poison gasp, pounce, rake (2 claws +5, 1d4+2)

So rake is the 2 claws +5? So roll a AC then for each claw +5?

There was one other when battling Pym, Shor, and Vosi it states

> DR 2/cold iron;
>   Weakness Vulnerable to fire;
>   shortbow +8 (1d2-2/*3 plus numbing cold)
>   Numbing Cold (DC 12)

What is cold iron? Could they use a torch to scare them off? Numbing cold just a constitution check 12 or greater?
How should I go about understanding these because they are used often in Reign of Winter.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  I can't help but notice you're asking a bunch of basic questions that are answered in the rulebook.  Please look at http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15582/i-have-read-the-dd-phb-but-am-still-having-trouble-grasping-some-of-the-basics?lq=1 and do a little research before asking - searching on www.d20pfsrd.com for any of these terms (or looking them up in the index of the rulebook) should help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For information on how to read a monster stat block, have a look at [this](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/introduction.html) section of the PRD. A number of standard creature abillities (such as Grab, Pounce, Rake and Poison) are explained [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/universalMonsterRules.html).

In answer to some of your specific questions -

1. The creature has a melee attack that is a short sword. The creature has a +3 to hit, and will do 1d6+1 points of damage. It will threaten a critical hit on a natural 19 or 20, rather than the standard 20. You may also see other attacks in the form of 1d8+1/x3 - these sorts of weapons will do more than the standard double damage on a crit. They could also be combined, such as 1d8+1/19-20x3, although that is unusual(I found exactly one creature with that sort of crit line - http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/additionalMonsters/daemon.html#_daemon,-purrodaemon).
2. For the Tatzlwyrm poison - it can breathe out poison gas at something it has grappled. This applies a Poison (you can find information on poisons in the [Glossary](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html)).
3. For the Tatzlwyrm attacks, it can normally bite, getting a +5 to hit, and doing 1d8+3 damage. If the attack hits, it also gets a free grapple attempt (the grab ability). If the grapple succeeds, then the creature can Rake - this allows a pair of claw attacks, hitting at +5 each, and doing 1d4+2 damage each.
4. Cold iron is a special material some weapons can be made from, found in the [Equipment](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/equipment.html) chapter - some creatures have damage reduction that can be negated by weapons made from this material. I'm not familiar with the Numbing Cold special ability - if it is a unique ability, it should be explained underneath the creature's stat block. The creature is Vulnerable to Fire, meaning it takes one and a half times as much damage from any Fire, so yes, perhaps a torch might scare one away. This would be up to you as a GM to rule on though - there are no standard mechanics for this sort of thing.

Comment: Slight correction to a solid answer: "Vulnerable to" is 50% more or 1.5 times the original amount of damage, not double. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Vulnerabilities-Ex-or-Su-

Answer (score 6):

This is several inter-related questions. I'll work my way down from the top.

> Melee short sword +3 (1d6+1/19-20)

You read that as the following:

- Melee Short Sword *(Weapon in use)*
- +3 *(Add this to your d20 roll as part of your attack)*
- 1d6+1 *(damage on a successful attack)*
- 19-20 *(if your d20 shows a 19 or 20, [you threaten a critical hit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Critical-Hits))*

If the last part (19-20) isn't specified, you can assume it's just "20".

> Special Attacks poison gasp, pounce, rake (2 claws +5, 1d4+2)

The rake is two attacks, each at +5 on the attack roll, each for 1d4+2 damage if they  hit. You don't roll AC, you roll an [attack roll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Roll) (d20 + 5 in this case) and hit if you equal or exceed the AC of the target.

> DR 2/cold iron;

[Cold Iron](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Iron-Cold) is a special material that weapons can be made out of. If you have a Cold Iron weapon, you can ignore the [damage reduction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction) in this case. (If you don't have a Cold Iron weapon, the monster takes 2 less damage from the attack.)

> Tatzlwyrm poison: Breath—inhaled; save Fort DC 12; frequency 1/round
>   for 2 rounds; effect 1d2 Str damage; cure 1 save. The save DC is
>   Constitution-based.

This one is better explained on the [monster's page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/tatzlwyrm). In short, that's a special ability that when it gets to use it, the target has to make a [Fortitude Save](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Saving-Throws) (DC 12). If they fail it, the attack does 1d2 Strength damage.

Here's the description of what [frequency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions) means:

> Frequency: This is how often the periodic saving throw must be
>   attempted after the affliction has been contracted (after the onset
>   time, if the affliction has any). While some afflictions last until
>   they are cured, others end prematurely, even if the character is not
>   cured through other means. If an affliction ends after a set amount of
>   time, it will be noted in the frequency. For example, a disease with a
>   frequency of “1/day” lasts until cured, but a poison with a frequency
>   of “1/round for 6 rounds” ends after 6 rounds have passed.